How am I using the nth term test wrong here?
I use the nth term test on the series below.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{3e^n}{1+e^{2n}}$$
By plugging in infinity I'd get:
$$\frac{3e^\infty}{1+e^{2\infty}}$$
In my mind this turns out to be
$$\frac{\infty}{\infty}$$
This is an indeterminate form which means the limit it does not exist. When I answer that the series diverges according to the nth term test the homework software says I'm wrong. What am I doing wrong here? Is it because the denominator outpaces the growth of the numerator by a factor of 2 and thus it ends up being zero?

You can not simply “plug in infinity.” Consider  the following  simpler example: Does $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n^2}$ exist?

"This is an intermediate form which means the limit it does not exist", fortunately, this is not correct

To expand on Sine of the Time's insightful comment: it's called an indeterminate form precisely because it might exist, but whether it does or not and the value it might take is not determined just by it looking like $\infty/\infty$, and hence called "indeterminate".

Note that, factoring out $e^n$ from numerator and denominator (or dividing by it), we obtain
$$\frac{3e^n}{1+e^{2n}}=\frac{e^n}{e^n}\frac{3}{\frac 1{e^n}+e^{n}}=\frac{3}{\frac 1{e^n}+e^{n}}$$
and then take the limit.

Of course $e^{2n}$ is stronger since $e^{2n}=(e^2)^n>e^n$ and this kind of algebraic manipulation are a standard way to show what happens in the limit.
As noticed in the comments we have an indeterminate form and therefore we can't "plug in" $\infty$ to obtain the result but we can easily eliminate the indetermination as shown, as for example for
$$\frac{3n}{1+n^2}=\frac{3}{\frac1n+n}$$
or the simpler $\frac n{n^2}=\frac1n$ already indicated in the comments.

Thank you for your answer. I'll make sure to algebraically manipulate the equation next time I see an intermediate form to try and get an actual answer.

You are welcome! Bye

Another way is to consider "squeezing" $$\frac3{2e^n}=\frac{3e^n}{e^{2n}+e^{2n}}\leqslant \frac{3e^n}{1+e^{2n}}\leqslant \frac{3e^n}{e^{2n}}=\frac3{e^n}$$
